# How to say refer to that section of this other document?

Tags: single-word-requests, acronyms

When writing a document, how to say "please refer to a specific section of another document" in a single word or using an acronyms?

For instance, I am writing a document (doc2) which is an extension of another document (doc1).

At some point I want to say please see section 3.1 of doc2.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want to use it? I'm assuming you're going to specify which section the reader should refer to, and it seems like that will take up at least another word.

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a basic [*see*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_signal#See) cite along with the [section symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign).

In other words, you could say:

> *See* Doc. 2 § 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of doing this is the oxford referencing guide. [Click here for examples.](http://guides.is.uwa.edu.au/c.php?g=325241&p=2177430)

You put a number at the point of reference and then at the end of the document you have the all of full references documented by number.

A crude example:

The results of the trial[1](http://guides.is.uwa.edu.au/c.php?g=325241&p=2177430) were disputed by a later report[2] which claimed that

Then at the end, under the title "References":

1. Full reference to the information on the trial.
2. Full reference to the information on the report.
3. etc...

In response to your edit, there is a less formal way of doing this where you would just write "see document x, section y". You sort of answered this yourself.